# When does document.readyState return the value 'complete'

Tags: javascript, dom, document-ready

When exactly does `'document.readyState'` return the value `'complete'`. 
Does it wait for all resources such as images, css files, javascripts files to be fulled loaded?
Does it wait for javascript code to be executed?

Comment: These days it's best to use the `DOMContentLoaded` event on the document to unambiguously get when the DOM is first parsed, but other resources are not yet loaded and then the `load` event on the `window` object when other resources (such as images and CSS stylesheets) are loaded.  There are no events when JS is done running.